# Filtering in vue.js not modifying datatable

Tags: vue.js, filter

I have been struggling for some days trying to filter some data in vue.js.

I have a search input in my website:

```
        <div class="search-wrapper panel-heading col-sm-2">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Filter by project name" />
        </div>
```

And a datatable where all the data is being displaced correctly:

```
    <datatable
        name="Proyectos"
        :headers="headers"
        :bulk-delete-records="bulkDeleteProjects"
        type="project"
        @check-all="checkAllProjects"
        :data="projectsForExport">
        <tr v-for="project in projects">
            <td v-text="project.ProjectID"></td>
            <td v-text="project.ProjectName"></td>
            <td class="row-actions">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" @click.prevent="goToProjectEdit(project.ProjectID)">
                    <i class="os-icon os-icon-ui-49"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="danger" href="javascript:void(0)" @click.prevent="openConfirmModal(project.ProjectID)">
                    <i class="os-icon os-icon-ui-15"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="checkbox" v-model="bulkDeleteProjects" :value="project.ProjectID" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </datatable>
```

I have put the proper code inside the computed tag inside the scoped script:

```
<script scoped>
    import { mapActions } from 'vuex';
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                headers: [
                    'ID PROYECTO',
                    'NOMBRE PROYECTO',
                    'ACCIONES'
                ],
                search: null,
                bulkDeleteProjects: []
            }
        },

        computed: {
    
            projects() {
                const projects = this.$store.getters['projects/projects'];
            
                if (_.isEmpty(this.search))
                {
                    return projects;
                }
                else
                {
                    return _.filter(projects, project => 
                    {
                        const search = this.search.toLowerCase();
                        return project.ProjectID.toLowerCase().includes(search)|| project.ProjectName.toLowerCase().includes(search);
                    });
                }
            }
            ...
```

If I change the "else" inside computed: projects() for something like "return null;", it removes all entries correctly but seems that any comparison with the data, although it returns true, does not modify the project's data.

But for some reason, it is not filtering. I haven't been able to find the reason why it's not working, so maybe you can point me out in the right direction.

Cheers!